# How to eliminate the space after chemical formula in mhchem enviornment

Tags: mhchem, xecjk, ctex

It's very convenient to use `mhchem` to typeset chemical formulas. It works very good in English writing, but when using Chinese (ctex), every chemical formula is followed by a space, which makes the text ugly. How to solve this small (but seemingly not so trivial) problem? Thanks.

Here is what I mean.

```
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
There is no space after \ce{HNO3} in English environment. 
如果是在中文的环境中\ce{HNO3}会有一个空格。
```

Which gives the result:

[image]

Comment: Probably `\ch{HNO3}` in combination with `\usepackage{chemformula}` is an alternative?

Comment: you can probably use `\unskip`  after `\ce{HNO3}` to remove the space, but please supply  complete small document not just a fragment so answers can be tested

Comment: Weird. Could be a bug in my package. I cannot test right now, so could you try `(\ce{HNO3})` in English? There should be no space between `3` and `)`.

Comment: @mhchem no space in that example

Comment: That space is added by xetex-only package `xeCJK`, which tries to automatically add a space between CJK characters and non-CJK ones. This works well for plain input, for example `abc<auto space>中文<auto space>abc`. However, in the case of `abc \cmd{...} abc`，`xeCJK` may make mistakes. When compiled with xetex, `ctex` auto loads `xeCJK`.

Comment: @mhchem `\ce` is not the only one which may cause problems with `xeCJK`. So don't worry. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/491) on the repository of `xeCJK`, to ask for a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The space appears to be added by the ctex code when switching from Latin script to Chinese. The above is generated with xelatex. Note the space is also added after `!!` placing an empty `\mbox{}` seems to suppress it, as shown in the last line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\showoutput
(\ce{HNO3})


AA \ce{HNO3} BB

中\ce{HNO3}会

中\ce{HNO3}!!会

中\ce{HNO3}\mbox{}会

\end{document}
```

with xetex the space seems to be added in the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` code, and for luatex the output is different, with no space after `!!` but still space after the Chemical formula.

[image]

Comment: Does anybody know why "The space appears to be added by the ctex code when switching from Latin script to Chinese"?

Comment: @mhchem I tried `texdoc ctex` but it's not the easiest read.